# chaincode bor has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode definition for 'bor' exists, but chaincode is not installed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I have set up a hyperledger fabric network shown below:
org1: peer0.org1
org2: peer0.org2

chaincodes:
1:deed.js
2:bor.js

I have installed chaincode deed.js on org1 and org2 peers. 
I have installed bor.js only on org2 peer.

I have approved chaincode deed.js on org1 and org2 peers. 
I have committed chaincode bor.js on org1 and org2 peers.

I have invoked chaincode deed.js using org1 and org2 peers.
I have invoked chaincode bor.js using org2 peer.

Querying deed.js works fine.
But querying bor.js is throwing an error:

Error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode bor has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode definition for 'bor' exists, but chaincode is not installed" .

I know the error is due to the reason that I have not installed chaincode bor.js on org1, but my project is such that I must install bor.js smart contract only on org2 but not on org1.

My endorsement policy for applications section of configtx.yaml is defined below:

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

```
# Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
# the application side of the network
Organizations:

# Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
# For Application policies, their canonical path is
#   /Channel/Application/<PolicyName>
Policies:
    Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    LifecycleEndorsement:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
    Endorsement:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Is there any way to perform the query operation on bor.js chaincode without an error by installing bor.js only on org2 peer?.

Answer (score 2):

See the answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73478194/9848275

It's likely due to a wrong `--package-id`.

Comment: In my case was wrong package id. I omitted 'sacc_1.0:' which isn't correct. It has to be like this -> echo $CC_PACKAGE_ID 
sacc_1.0:541acc921b0810039a2fc680c29117070d4ff89b76c7b96627c5ae984effade8

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct you created one channel and you are trying to install 2 chain codes.

Check whether you have correctly installed your deed and bor chain codes on your resp peers.
Check with these commands:

`peer chaincode list --installed
peer chaincode list --instantiated -C yourchannelname`

If 2 chaincode exist then cross-check your CouchDB whether the data stores into a ledger or not. If data is storing in your CouchDB, then check your command and the peer on which you are querying or invoking.
If any queries I can help you

Comment: Yeah. I created a channel and two peers one for each of two organizations. I need to install deed chaincode on org1 peer and org2 peer followed by bor chaincode only on org2 peer. Is it possible to do that way? Both org1 and org2 peers on same channel. I'm using fabric 2.0 version

Comment: add one more consortium  parameters(only ordg2) into your configtx.yaml.

Comment: my profiles section looks like these                                                                                         TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
    tell me where i need to do changes..I'm newbie so please help me out

Comment: As of now, you have one consortium, create one more consortium SampleConsortium1: Organizations:  - *Org2 . Then try

Comment: after creating consortium is there any changes to be made in TwoOrgasChannel section:  TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Comment: Did you checked either chaincode is installed or not by using commands ???

Comment: Yeah I have checked . I have installed deed chaincode on org1 and org2. bor chaincode on org2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your --package-id starts with the chaincode label.

e.g.,

```
chaincode label = sacc_1.0
export CHAINCODE_ID=sacc_1.0:541acc921b0810039a2fc680c29117070d4ff89b76c7b96627c5ae984effade8
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need only to grant internet access to your peer as Chaincode looks for Internet to install its dependencies.