# "chaincode definition for 'fabcar' exists, but chaincode is not installed" Error when i try to invoke chaincode in HLF2.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I'm following this tutorial — https://kctheservant.medium.com/multi-host-deployment-for-first-network-hyperledger-fabric-v2-273b794ff3d.

I've successfully installed, approved and committed chaincode on both peers.

These are installed chaincodes on host1 and host2 respectively:

```
Installed chaincodes on peer:
Package ID: fabcar_1:7ed63d49b5b7ff8f8f17cf3106975e1b731b3d1f7c417ef050a24315ef828085, Label: fabcar_1
Package ID: fabcar_1:a8fdf3e70eaa79c8481356484661fe3c763b5fc744ca82c8c564ece77a83cf8b, Label: fabcar_1
Package ID: fabcar_1:cd4f25953c7b04623652da137067c386062bf1b9a6de0e710c72f11e81c7ea0c, Label: fabcar_1
```

```
Installed chaincodes on peer:
Package ID: fabcar_1:7ed63d49b5b7ff8f8f17cf3106975e1b731b3d1f7c417ef050a24315ef828085, Label: fabcar_1
```

Also commit status of peers:

```
Committed chaincode definition for chaincode 'fabcar' on channel 'mychannel':
Version: 1, Sequence: 2, Endorsement Plugin: escc, Validation Plugin: vscc, Approvals: [Org1MSP: true, Org2MSP: true]
```

And so when I try to invoke chaincode with

```
docker exec cli peer chaincode invoke -o orderer3.example.com:9050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n fabcar --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"Args":["initLedger"]}'
```

I get such error:

```
Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"make sure the chaincode fabcar has been successfully defined on channel mychannel and try again: chaincode definition for 'fabcar' exists, but chaincode is not installed"
```

`CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION` is set to **true** if it'll help.
Nodes are running in docker.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've experience the same issue and it was due to using the wrong `--package-id`  when approving the chain-code.

More info [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html#invoke-failure)

Answer (score 0):

Just write docker ps -a. and check the chaincode logs. clean solution